# Count & Sum of Order Values for each customer (through iteration) in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, for-loop

I have Customer & Order models as below:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Order(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I would like to generate a table of (distinct) customers along with a count of number of orders placed by each of them and the sum of values of those orders. I tried this in the views.py:

```
def customers(request):
    customer_orders = Order.objects.distinct().annotate(Sum('value'))
```

Then in my html template, I tried the following:

```
<ul>
{% for customer in customer_orders %}
    <li>{{customer.customer}} - {{customer.value__sum}}<li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

After all this, instead of getting unique customers (and respective order records), I'm getting a list of all orders and customers are getting repeated (as shown below). Not sure what I'm missing here.

Bosco-Ward - 16,700.0
Ernser PLC - 51,200.0
Murphy Ltd - 21,400.0
Kohler-Veum - 29,200.0
Schmidt-Legros - 96,800.0
Brown-Weissnat - 8,200.0
Bosco-Ward - 36,400.0
Ernser PLC - 66,600.0
Murphy Ltd - 84,200.0

Also wanted to know if there's a possibility to generate a table of city names with order count and total value of orders received from that city (note that my order model doesn't have city field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a queryset of `Customer` instances make your query on the `Customer` model itself instead of on `Order`, next I believe you will not need to use `distinct` here since the customer instances should be considered unique. Hence, you can make a query like:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Sum


customers = Customer.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('order'), order_value_sum=Sum('order__value'))


for customer in customers:
    print(customer.name, customer.order_count, customer.order_value_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note im typing the solution from my phone without testing it but this is what i think:

1. Give a related name to customer in Order model:

customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=“orders”)

2. Get orders count:

Customer.objects.get(id=1).orders.count()

Or access this attribute in template something like:

{{ customer.orders.count }}

3. Get orders count values by city

From django.db.models import Count, Sum

Customer.objects.values(“city”).annotate(order_count=Count(“orders”)).annotate(totals=Sum(“value”))

Comment: {{ customer.orders.count }} works perfectly fine.  Is there also a way to get the 'sum' instead of count?

Customer.objects.values(“city”).annotate(order_count=Count(“orders”)).annotate(totals=Sum(“value”))

throws an error stating that the Customer model doesn't have a field 'value'. If I remove the last part (annotation of Sum), the code works fine and displays the count of orders for the cities

Comment: Sorry, try to change the last part to: annotate(totals=Sum(“orders__value”))

Answer (score 0):

Add realted_name to `Order` `customer` field:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Order(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
```

query:

```
Customer.objects.values(“city”).annotate(order_count=Count(“orders”)).annotate(totals=Sum(“orders__value”))
```